# H2O Frame apply function on each row in python

Tags: h2o

I am looking for a method similar to the 'apply' function in pandas. I tried

```
my_H2Oframe.apply(lambda x: my_function(x), axis=1)
```

But this doesn't work.

> ValueError: Unimplemented: op < my_function > not bound in H2OFrame

I found [this question](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/h2ostream/ag8NWxDyBqg). It seems we can only use those functions that have already been defined by H2O. I think there must be a method similar to the apply function because this is a common operation. Does anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no other apply type method at the moment. the H2O apply method is suppose to be a close equivalent to pandas apply. It is true that H2O's apply function is limited to certain operations such as addition (+), subtraction (-), division, etc. If you use one that H2O doesn't have you will get the error above.

here are a few examples to try to see how the apply function can work (first one gets the mean across columns, the second returns a boolean column):

```
h2oframe = h2o.import_file("http://h2o-public-test-data.s3.amazonaws.com/smalldata/prostate/prostate.csv")

h2oframe.apply(lambda x: x.mean(), axis=0)

h2oframe.apply(lambda x: x['PSA'] > x['VOL'],axis=1)
```

And here is the current documentation on it:

```
apply(fun=None, axis=0):
    Apply a lambda expression to an H2OFrame.

    Parameters: 
    fun – a lambda expression to be applied per row or per column.
    axis – 0 = apply to each column; 1 = apply to each row
    Returns:    
    a new H2OFrame with the results of applying fun to the current frame.
```

Comment: I could not find the documentation of which operations are supported.
For example, I would like to get the largest value from the prediction columns: test_h2o.apply((lambda x: x.max()), axis=1)